# Access values from CArray pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, pointers, mfc

I have a class which has a CArray object, I need to get values from this CArray to another class, but so far have failed to do so.

```
class CTempGridClass: public CTableCtrl {
public:
    CArray<CArray<float,float>, CArray<float,float>&> *m_row2;
};

class CCorePassageAreasPage : public CDialog {
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CCorePassageAreasPage)
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_CORE_PASSAGE_AREA };
    CArray<CArray<float,float>, CArray<float,float>&> m_row;
    CTempGridClass Grid;
};

BOOL CCorePassageAreasPage::OnSetActive() {
    Grid.m_row2 = &m_row;
}
```

How can I access m_row2 values? I tried

```
float x  = m_row2[0][1];
```

but this gives out an "'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CArray' to 'float'" error. I can do the above assignment to m_row without any errors.

I know that I can avoid this by using a vector instead, but the 'CCorePassageAreasPage' is created by someone else and I don't want to change it.

Comment: what about `x = m_row2->operator[](nrow)[j]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m_row2` is a pointer; so `m_row2[nRow]` would refer to element `nRow` of an array of `CArray`, if it pointed an array. Since it (presumably) only points to a single object, it just accesses invalid memory.

You almost certainly don't want it to be a pointer; since you say the class "has" it, it should just be a member with no unnecessary indirection.

If you do want a pointer for some reason, then you'll need to dereference it to access the array it points at:

```
float x  = (*m_row2)[nRow][j];
```